# Duplicate question but what if you still have questions or old accepted answer is wrong/not relevant now

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Some new questions get closed because they are duplicates. They link to an older question which is old, has an accepted answer and probably no more looked at.

Well... what if the new question needs fresher answers? The accepted answer from the old question could be obsolete, no more relevant, wrong under current circumstances, does not apply.. etc?

What if one has further questions to the old accepted answer? I am depending on the fact that that person is willing to answer or is still around. Do you add the question as a comment under the accepted answer for the old question?

Comment: For next time, you don't need to CW your posts on Meta.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-old-unanswered-questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Add a new question, link to old questions explaining the reason it didn't give you the complete answer you needed.

2) Add a new question, then leave a comment for the original answerer pointing him to the new question.

Comment: This answer does not work unfortunately. I do this, and I get 7+ downvotes and my question gets closed. – Protected Identity 1 min ago edit

Answer (score 3):

If you're contemplating asking such a question, you should do your due diligence and 
search for possible duplicates before posting.  If the answers for a potential duplicate
fall into the categories you mention (no longer valid, different circumstances, etc), 
you can point out the older question, and explain how the new question differs from 
the potential dupe.  If you can make a good enough case for not-a-dupe, it probably 
won't be closed.

Answer (score 1):

The accept mark just means that the answer helped the asker. New answers can still be added and a new answer getting enough votes will be almost as visible to anyone viewing the question.

If you think the question needs an up-to-date answer, you could always add a bounty to it. This will give it more attention and let people know that someone is still looking for an answer.

Comment: Users looking for gaining more points tend to ignore questions with accepted answers. Why spend time on these questions if you know questions can have only one accepted answer and therefore they will spend more time on more rewarding questions. I don't like the bounty system. I used it once and I lost my points to an answer that didn't do me any good. The current bounty system rewards to at least one answer regardless if it helped you.